# Why System.Char[] output, not value of string?

Tags: string, f#

```
let reverseString (myStr: string)=
    myStr|>Seq.toList|>List.rev |> Array.ofList|>string
```

I am working in F# for this function. I run the above one and want to get the result for example I did

```
reverseString "abc"
```

I expected it will show `cba` but actually it returns System.Char[]. So what can be the problem because I want to see that result like "cba" instead to check if I am doing right or not. Thank you!

Comment: Strange, your code seems to be running fine on my side. Are you evaluating it in F# interactive?

Comment: @katie do you have a `open System` statement above that or is your `String` lowercase? Because when I use `string` I replicate your result, but when I use `System.String` I get the correct output.

Comment: You can also fully qualify the F# type alias ``string`` (and use a slightly different approach for less conversions): ``let reverseString (myStr : string) = myStr.ToCharArray () |> Array.rev |> Core.string``

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the problem could be a confusion between the constructor of `System.String` and `string` the function.

`string` the function converts any object into a string by basically calling `ToString()` which for a Char array just outputs the type name: `System.Char[]`.

On the other hand `System.String` the class has several overloaded constructors one of which is an array of chars so it produces a string:

```
[| 'a'; 'b'; 'c'|] |> string  |> printfn "%A" //   "System.Char[]"
[| 'a'; 'b'; 'c'|].ToString() |> printfn "%A" //   "System.Char[]"
[| 'a'; 'b'; 'c'|] |> String  |> printfn "%A" //   "abc" 

6                  |> string  |> printfn "%A" //   "6"
6                 .ToString() |> printfn "%A" //   "6"
6                  |> String  |> printfn "%A" //  error: no overloads for int

"abc"              |> string  |> printfn "%A" //   "abc"
"abc"             .ToString() |> printfn "%A" //   "abc"
"abc"              |> String  |> printfn "%A" //   Strangelly enough gives error too
```

Comment: Regarding your last line: it's not strange at all if you realize that ``System.String`` does not have a constructor which takes a single argument of type ``string`` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2).